# How to check multiple bools in one

Tags: c#, .net, boolean

I need to create a manager that allows to add/remove bools and then have one condition to check if any are true.

I created a list and then used Contains(true) to check if any were true but then I realized that it doesn't re-check the bool methods (for example some of the bools will check if a certain button is being pressed).

Any ideas instead of creating a long list of if statements?

```
public static List<bool> BoolList = new List<bool>() { example() };

public static bool example(){
    return textBox1.Contains("test");
}

//Loop
if (BoolList.Contains(true)) {}
```

Comment: Show us your code instead of describing it.

Comment: At a guess, you want a `List<Func<bool>>` instead of `List<bool>`. But as David said, you need to show the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: @Fetix: the term missing in your question is that you want to check the conditions lazily, so evaluate the condition when you ask for it not at initialization.

Comment: Please do not deface your question

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a list of `Func<bool>`. Instead of passing in the result of the function, you pass in the function itself. For example:

```
public static List<Func<bool>> FuncList = new List<Func<bool>>
{ 
    isleftdown, isRightDown, otherFunc
};
```

And to check the results with some simple Linq:

```
// Are all functions true:
var allTrue = FuncList.All(f => f());

// Are any functions true:
var anyTrue = FuncList.Any(f => f());

// Are all functions false:
var anyFalse = FuncList.All(f => !f());
```